# Get the 2nd last successful artifact from teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I can use the .lastSuccessful to get the last Successful artifact. However anyway to get the 2nd last successful artifact. Been looking for ages and can't find anything :(

I need somethinh like  (.lastSuccessful - 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no simple way without using the API like http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin